# I want to create a styled component, which inherits some properties from another predefined styled component. How to achieve that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I have a component which I export from a helper file:

```
export const BaseStyle = styled.Text`
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.gray900};
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 40px;
`;
```

And I am trying to create another styled component which wraps a third party component, but also applies all the styles from BaseStyle

```
const FinalComponent = styled(thirdPartyComponent)`
    background-color: red;
    //My goal is to spread the styles of BaseStyle here somehow
`;
```

Is this achievable in React Native?

Comment: @possum No as styled components is not used in the suggested thread and I am asking a styled components related question.

Comment: You could extract out common css with styled.css``. and then use it in BaseStyle as well as your FinalComponent.